# How to handle missing data in time series in R?

Tags: programming

I have 5 years stock closing price of a company with some missing values in between (I having 1443 data points).

When I create timeseries object in R with frequency 365 it creates 1834 data points, R is imputing these missing values for timeseries object but can anyone help me how it is imputing them? like what formula is used? Also if i don't want to impute these missing values is it possible in R?

R command used:

```
st_ts = ts(stocks[,2],start = c(2010,1),end = c(2015,9),frequency = 365)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't the time series package already inputting missing data point for you? Or does it assume the last 397 are empty only? can you include a plot of this timeseries object in your question?

Comment: yes it does but how do i know what values and how it imputes for large datasets?

Comment: Hi SRKX yes i have looked in that object it is giving different values for different missing fields ,but i did not understand how i is imputing those values so i asked this question

Comment: ok so it seems the data are repeated, and it seems you're original set only has about 300 points...

Comment: `ts` is probably not the right package for you, have a look at [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) for more info.

Comment: This is a programming question. And your example is not reproducible. If you deliver an example you could get an aswer on stackoverflow . I also assume that ts is not the right class for you.

Comment: Try xts and provide valud time-stamps. Then nothing will be imputed.